# html: print linked element bold

Tags: html, css

Hey I link between 2 pages with the following solution
First page (first.html):

```html
<a href="sample.html#abc">1</a>
<a href="sample.html#def">2</a> 
<a href="sample.html#ghi">3</a>
```

Second page (sample.html):

```html
<p id="abc">abc</p>
<p id="def">def</p>
<p id="ghi">ghi</p>
```

Question:
How to style the element the user was linked to special with stock css?
I know there are ways to do this with js but I really want this to be done with plain css and not javascript so yeah; help is appreciated :D

Example:
User clicks link 3 (ghi) -> the text 'ghi' is red or underlined or whatever

Thanks already :p

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/, maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `:target`. Example at https://stackoverflow.211368e.repl.co/.